# Instabug shake event not working

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, instabug

I have implemented Instabug in my application from [here](https://instabug.com/) 
 and integrate it perfectly and its all functionalities are working perfectly other then shake event.

```
public class VapeMail extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Instabug.initialize(this, Constants.INSTABUG_ID)
                .setShowIntroDialog(true, MainActivity.class)
                .setInvocationEvent(Instabug.IBGInvocationEvent.IBGInvocationEventShake);
    }
}
```

I have checked all possibilities by changing thresh hold value but shaking option of instabug not responding any thing. Other then shaking all other events like `IBGInvocationEventTwoFingersSwipeLeft` and `IBGInvocationEventFloatingButton` are working and responding correctly but why the shaking event is not responding. I have followed all steps given on the website of instabug but nothing is happened when I shake my device. I checked my shake sensors also they are working perfectly.
Any help would be appreciable thanks.

Comment: This is Hassan from Instabug. Can you set Instabug.DEBUG = true; before initialization and attach the logs from logcat after shaking the device? You can also reach us at contactus@instabug.com

Comment: Ok I tried again shaking is working but I have  to shake very hard to show the dialogue. I need to know what should be the threshold value I should set to show response with little shaking. thanks

Comment: The default value should be easy to invoke, but not too easy to invoke by accident. If that's not the case, what device are you testing with? You could try setting the threshold to a low value, to increase sensitivity, with setShakingThreshold(0.001f). This value should make it highly sensitive though.

Comment: unfortunately, `setShakingThreshold(0.001f)` is deprecated. Any other method I can use?

Answer (score 1):

There is no conflict in the documents. It is all about which SDK version that's being used. I recommend that you use the latest version. Here is the [latest](https://docs.instabug.com/docs/ios-invocation) documentation.

You can talk to Instabug team anytime from [here](https://docs.instabug.com/docs/helpful-resources#section-contact-us), and they will always help.